# Is it advisable to declare pointer to heap memory as `const` ALWAYS?

Tags: c++, coding-style

```
T *p = new T();
```

For the pointer on heap, there can be disastrous operations such as,

```
p++;  // (1) scope missed
p = new T(); // (2) re-assignment
```

Which would result in memory leaks or crashes due to wrong `delete`. Apart from using smart pointers, is it advisable **always** to make heap pointer a `const`;

```
T* const p = new T();  // now "p" is not modifiable
```

This question is in regards of maintaining good programming practice and coding style.

Comment: But suppose you *want* or *need* to modify it?

Comment: @Neil, I haven't seen such use cases often till now in the real code. In case if it's require, then compiler will complain and we can change that particular pointer to the normal one. My question is for general programming practice.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, I actually never used const pointers (not to confuse with pointer to const).

Comment: @Neil: there's always:
 int * const i = new int;
 int* &j = const_cast<int*>(i);

Comment: Isn't this what references are for? Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @jjwchoy Nope, that is not what references are for.

Comment: The best option is not to have a raw pointer variable at all; use the result of `new` to initialise a smart pointer, and that will take care of deleting it for you. It's difficult to write exception-safe code otherwise, whether or not you make the pointer `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate to say **always**, but what you propose seems reasonable for many/most cases.  Const correctness is something most C++ folks pay a fair bit of attention to in function parameters, but not so much in local (or even member) variables.  We might be better off to do so.

Comment: The trouble is, data members are often logically const but physically not - hence the popularity of `mutable`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, about the only time I use raw heap pointers is if writing my own data structures. and if you used a const pointer for them, your data structure immediately becomes unassignable. which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Why unassignable ? You have 2 objects; with both allocated to heap. When you copy it, **mostly** you will do deep copy (which is still possible) and not shallow copy (not allowed with `const`); Isn't it ?

Comment: I said assign, not copy. You will almost certainly need to change the pointer. And I don't find the terms deep- and shallow- copy at all helpful in a C++ context.

Answer (score 2):

There is one major potential problem I see with this:

after `delete` you should set the pointer to NULL to (help) prevent it being used in other parts of the code.

Const will not allow you to do this.

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Andrei, I think what @Neil means, that at end of destructor or function you really don't need to assign `null`

Comment: @Andrei Been discussed here zillions of times - bottom line a) false sense of security, b) pointless. And just because C++ allows you to delete the NULL pointer doesn't mean your code should normally be doing that.

Comment: @Neil: While I understand your point, the trouble is not everybody lives in the land where all the code is "good code". A null pointer exception is easier to diagnose after a crash than whatever UB there might be after an access via that pointer into re-allocated memory.

Comment: @Neil: It probably depends on the project & type/quality of code, but having seen lots of bugs that came down to object members being used just after release/deletion (and thus usually going unnoticed except on the odd occasion where the memory was immediately re-used), I'd argue it isn't pointless at all. Better for that code to always crash with a null pointer access, so you find & fix it, than once in a blue moon so it's a mystery. (Ofc. the trade-off is if you null things you no longer crash on a double-free. But, at least in my experience, use-after-free is more common than double-free.)

Comment: @Leo A null pointer access will not always cause a crash - it will always cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suspect the difference in opinions on this one boils down to people who usually work alone versus people who usually work with others.  (And @Neil, in practice, a NULL pointer dereference will cause an immediate crash on every platform I bet you can name.)

Comment: @Nemo OK, I can name zillions that it probably doesn't - any platform that does not support memory protection. And I don't like you assuming how I work. As it happens I've been a project manager/consultant on at least a dozen teams, the largest of which was circa 20 programmers.

Comment: @Neil: Fair enough.  But 99.99% of the people reading this are developing for Unix (incl. MacOS), Windows, or maybe some iDevice, where debugging a NULL pointer derefence is trivial compared to use-after-free.  It's just silly to call this style "pointless" in such environments.

Comment: @Nemo I think you vastly underestimate the number of embedded programmers. And it's still a pointless thing to do for the reasons that have been enumerated here many, many times before.

Comment: And I think everyone is missing the point. Raw pointers in user code should be very rare things indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is unusual to use a pointer if it is not going to change. Perhaps because I hardly ever use `new` in normal code, but rely on container classes.

Otherwise it is generally a good idea to preserve const-correctness by making things const whenever possible.

Comment: I don't think it is so unusual. Consider a map of names to polymorphic objects. This will almost certainly be implemented as `map <string,Base *>` and the pointers may well never change.